# Which of Tolkiens works describes the populations around and past the Sea of Rhun?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

Are there any parts of Tolkiens books that outline in more detail the populations and life East of Rhun? I have seen differences in locations of cities and towns around the Sea of Rhun itself, as well as an Island in the centre that sometimes is omitted in other maps.. I'm wanting to know what is the best and most detailed description of this part of middle earth.

Comment: Also related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79727, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69222 and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/48088

Comment: Thanks, this third link has the maps to lead my search further. Looking more into more detail around the Sea of Rhun to start with, but trying to get back into my project mapping the locations around ME in a GIS so the more detailed maps of the continent are just what I'm after, Cheers @DarthSatan

Answer (score 2):

I can find very little. Tolkien devotes a small amount of space to describing the "uttermost East" in "The Hiding of Valinor", which was published in *The History of Middle-Earth I: The Book of Lost Tales Part 1* (emphasis mine):

> Wherefore said some [of the assembled Elves, Valar, and Maiar]: "Let us send now messengers to discover the fashion of the world in the uttermost East beyond even the sight of Manwë from the Mountain of the World." Then arose Oromë: "That I can tell you, for I have seen. **In the East beyond the tumbled lands there is a silent beach and a dark and empty sea.**"

Comment: I've always really liked the last line of this quote. It makes the East sound like a very remote and lonely place.